# In how many lists does the word appear?

Tags: python

I have different lists in python:

```
list1 = [hello,there,hi]
list2 = [my,name,hello]
```

I need to make a dictionary with the key being the number of lists a word appears in. So my answer would look like
{2:hello,1:hi ....}

I am new to python and I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: What did you try? And please have a look at [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: **Note** 1. Key of a dictionary is unique 2. Strings in Python is always quoted 3. If you need to name lists with numeric suffix, its better to create list of lists. Once you are through with this, check the Python library, collections for a module called Counter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a dictionary to store key-value results.

Here is some code to help you get started, but you'll has to modify to your exact solution.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

list1 = ["hello","there","hi"]
list2 = ["my","name","hello"]

result = dict()

for word in list1:
    if word in result.keys():
        result[word] = result[word] + 1
    else:
        result[word] = 1

for word in list2:
    if word in result.keys():
        result[word] = result[word] + 1
    else:
        result[word] = 1

print result
```

Comment: Instead of writing code for free. tell the way to do .Since OP need to put effort . then we can help

Comment: While I understand what you mean, sometimes it is helpful to see code to push you along. Then you will look over it, parse it, understand it. That's helped me in my learning experience.

Comment: I am sorry, I guess I should have been more clear. I essentially have a list of lists. Each list contains different words. For each word in each list I need to know in how many different lists does it appear. I am doing this to find the inverse document frequency of the word.

Comment: Right, I understand the code above just represents the total count of the number of times the words appear, not how many lists they appear in. So yes, you will have to modify the code so that 1. you iterate over ALL lists to start and add a dictionary entry for each word, and then 2, iterate over each list, for each unique word per list and increment the counts.

Answer (score 1):

As first step, make reverse dictionary like so

initialize it

```
words_count = {}
```

and then for each list of words do like so

```
for word in list_of_words:
    if not word in words_count:
        words_count[word] = 1
    else:
        words_count[word] += 1
```

then reverse words_count like so:

```
inv_words_count = {v: k for k, v in words_count.items()}
```

inv_words_count is the desired result

Answer (score 1):

I have slightly modified your input lists (list1 & list2) as shown below:

```
list1 = ['hello,there,hi'] # Added quotes as it is a string
list2 = ['my,name,hello']
```

Here is the logic:

```
list1 = list1[0].split(',')
list2 = list2[0].split(',')
list_final = list1 + list2

dict_final = {}

for item in list_final:
    if item in dict_final.keys():
        dict_final.update({item:(dict_final.get(item) + 1)})
    else:
        dict_final.update({item:1})
```

Hope it will work as you are expecting :)